# Pick a random element of a group of integers in a matrix using Python

Tags: python

I have a matrix filled with 100 integers. These integers are a mix of 0's, 1's, and 2's. How can I pick a random 0 of this matrix? Is there a function for this issue?

Edit: I also need to know the origin position of this random 0 (zero) in the matrix because I have to swap this zero with another value afterwards

Comment: your question is not clear for me. Could you please add an example, with expected behavior.

Comment: By random 0 do you mean the indexes of a 0 picked at random from all of the indexes of elements that are 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your matrix is an array of arrays in the form:

```
A = [[0, 0, 1],
     [0, 1, 0]]
```

I am also assuming you want a random pair of indexes drawn uniformly from all index pairs whose element is 0. If you were selecting the element it would be 0 every time. You could do this:

```
import random

A = # your matrix

# generate the pairs
zero_indexes = [(i, j)
  # for each index along each axis
  for i in range(len(A)) 
  for j in range(len(A[i]))
  # keep the pair if it's element is 0
  if A[i][j] == 0]

# make a random pick from your pairs
random_zero = random.choice(zero_indexes)
print(random_zero)
```

Update: You mentioned wanting to swap this randomly selected 0 with another value and this can be done with my approach like so (this can be added onto the end of the block above):

```
i, j = random_zero
A[i][j] = # your new value
```

Comment: thank you :) I forgot to mention that I need to know the origin position of this random zero in the matrix because I have to swap this zero with another value at the end. THX

Comment: What do you mean by origin position? How is that different than the index pair I provided? The variable `random_zero` is a tuple so you can do this `i, j = random_zero` and then plug those back into your matrix like so `A[i][j] = n` to update this location.

Answer (score 2):

From the way you've described the issue it looks like the following code will do:

```
print(0)
```